# Biblatex apa-style produces uncessesary comma

Tags: biblatex, apa-style, german

I have a problem with citations from multiple authors. An additional comma is added after the 2nd author and before the german 'und' ('and' in English). How can I remove this comma?

Actual it looks like: Van der Panne, Van Beers, und Kleinknecht (2003)

Should be: Van der Panne, Van Beers und Kleinknecht (2003)

The code looks like this:

```
% !TEX TS-program = xelatexmk
% !TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[bookmarksopen=true,colorlinks=true,linkcolor=black,citecolor=black,urlcolor=black,breaklinks=true]{hyperref}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel,translator}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Arial}

% APA german
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=apa]{biblatex}
\DeclareLanguageMapping{ngerman}{ngerman-apa}
\bibliography{lib}

\begin{document}
\textcite{vanderpanne2003} haben herausgefunden, dass...
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

The Bibtex entry looks like below:

```
@article{vanderpanne2003,
    Author = {Van der Panne, Gerben and Van Beers, Cees and Kleinknecht, Alfred},
    Date = {2003},
    Journaltitle = {International Journal of Innovation Management},
    Number = {3},
    Pages = {309--338},
    Shorttitle = {Success and Failure of Innovation},
    Timestamp = {2017-01-08T11:24:29Z},
    Title = {Success and Failure of Innovation: A Literature Review},
    Volume = {7}}
```

Comment: Which version of `biblatex-apa` are you running? With the current v. 7.2 I get 'Van der Panne, Van Beers und Kleinknecht' in citations without a comma.

Comment: Thanks for the little hint. I have updated my tex distribution and now it works like expected.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the problem was solved by updating the `biblatex-apa` package. In the current version the German localisation does not use the Oxford comma.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This behaviour is due to a bug in `biblatex-apa` which is fixed
in the current (2017/01/06) release (v7.4). Where possible, you should [update your TeX
distribution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/55437) to install the
current release. If this is not possible, for example if you want to
change only this one package or where you do not have the privileges
to update the entire distribution, you will need to [install the
package locally](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1137).  This option should be considered a last resort, since for more complex packages there may be package dependencies that will make local installation more complicated and error-prone.

Comment: Answer as per http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6988/questions-which-are-bug-reports-revisited/7008#7008